# how to pass a php variable in a href link with javascript window open

Tags: javascript, php

The code below works to call a JS window.open

```
<?
$facebookID = "ID";
$parameters = array(
                'app_id' => 'app_ID',
                'to' => $facebookID,
                'link' => 'link',
                'redirect_uri' => 'my_url'
                );
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?'.http_build_query($parameters);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open('.json_encode($url).');</script>';
?>
```

CODE ABOVE WORKS... it opens a window with the facebook send dailog

But how can I implement this in a link to call this window on click only with the specefic facebook ID...

I build my page with multiple faceboook ID like this:

```
<?
// CODE ABOVE.....
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{ 
     $facebookID = $row['facebookID'];

     $parameters = array(
                'app_id' => 'app_ID',
                'to' => $facebookID,
                'link' => 'link',
                'redirect_uri' => 'my_url'
                );

     $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?'.http_build_query($parameters);

    ?>

    <a href="#">ON CLICK CALL the JavaScript for this specefic Facebook User</a>
    <? 
    }
    ?>
```

What should be my href="....."  ?  I tried the following, but it didn't work... I guess it's because of the php variable inside the window.open...

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('.json_encode($url).');" </a>
```

thanks

Comment: Show the html. You php code has no "<?php" and "?> and i don't know if the code is inside of a "echo", print, etc.

Comment: Wild guess, but shouldn't the href be the actual URL to your PHP script, or if you don't want to redirect, just a hash ?

Comment: @adeneo no, that doesn'T work.. it calls /.jason_encode($url)

Comment: The real question is why would you use `json_encode` there, and not supply the expected arguments ?

Comment: It's supposed to be  `window.open(url, name, [features]);`, it doesn't expect JSON ?

Comment: @adeneo I took this code from someone that works in a blank page `<script type="text/javascript">window.open('.json_encode($url).');</script>';`  so they put json_encode in the window.open and everything works... I just can't figure out how to call this on click and not when the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use json encode inside of window.open with double quotes in your attributes because the json_encode will add double quotes to your code.

[image]

(see that the attribute onclick is "fighting" with your double quotes from window.open)

**If you invert** the single quotes to double quotes, it will work properly using json_encode.

```
$url = 'http://test.com';
echo "<a href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='window.open(" . json_encode($url) . ");'>Test</a>";
```

(because the json encode will add double quotes and your attributes have single quotes.)

**Another way to do it** (that i recommend)
is remove the json_encode and put single quotes inside your php.

```
$url = 'http://test.com';
echo '<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open(' . '\'' . $url . '\'' . ');">Test</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(' . json_encode($url) . '); return false;">ON CLICK CALL the JavaScript for this specefic Facebook User</a>';
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, it just opens a new window with the same test URL with a # at the end